# Getting the default document editor toolbar in Mac Catalyst

Tags: macos, uikit, appkit, mac-catalyst, uidocument

I’ve just started porting my iPad app to the Mac using Catalyst. It’s a document editor and uses `UIDocument`. I’m trying to get the default toolbar behaviour for a document editor on macOS where there’s a dropdown to quickly name, tag, and move the document, and a subtitle that shows if the document has been edited. I can’t see any way to do this with Catalyst — is it possible?

Thanks,

Luke

[image: Screenshot of Preview]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A representative from Apple confirmed to me that this is not possible using Catalyst. In my opinion this makes Catalyst unsuitable for document based apps at the moment (Big Sur is currently the latest version of macOS).